# Explaination of while(false !== ($f=readdir($d))){

Tags: php, directory, conditional-statements

I have just started practicing OOP in php through the book Concepts, Techniques and Codes. Unluckily I have never worked with directories and files in PHP and feeling difficulty to understand this condition here is the full code

```
function DirectoryItems($directory){
  $d = "";
  if(is_dir($directory)){
     $d = opendir($directory) or die("Couldn't open directory.");
     while(false !== ($f=readdir($d))){
      if(is_file("$directory/$f")){
      $this->filearray[] = $f;
}
}
closedir($d);
}else{
//error
die("Must pass in a directory.");
}
}
```

All I can understand is first we check the parameter that is it directory after that we open that directory and than we read the directory and putt all the files in the directory into an array but the condition is confusing me what the heck is !== I know only about !=

This book is written in PHP4 and 5 btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The !== is like != but in addition to checking the equality it also checks the type.

This is an important distinction because sometimes something is "falsey" or "truthy" but not really a Boolean type with a value of false or true. The number 0 for example is generally treated as false.

The second slightly confusing part here is that the code is checking `false !== (assignment)` in the while loop. This is basically checking if the assignment was for a valid value.

So to out it all together code:

```
while(false !== ($f=readdir($d))
```

...translates to something like:

While `$f` is assigned an object from `readdir($d)` do ...

Comment: Be very careful here, this code has just cost me a late night: when the directory does not exist, this creates an infinite loop. Along with error logging every attempt. this loop is a nightmare! The problem is that it does not return an explicit boolean false when the directory resource itself is false. The documentation for this function is partly to blame it seems!

Answer (score 1):

`===` means "equal value and equal type"
`!==` means "not equal value or not equal type"

Using `==`, and empty string is equal to false. Using `===` though, they are not equal because the type is different.

`!=` and `!==` work the same way. The extra `=` sign means that type should be checked too, not just equivalent values.

Comment: so in this condition we are making sure that the value and file types are equal and that mean we are putting files having similar types in to the array?

Comment: The keyword here being type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` will coerce values to the same type to compare them. If the `readdir` returns `0`, then `False==0` will probably evaluate to be true. However, `False===0` will not be true.

There are a lot of people who know a lot more about comparison operators, type coercion, value types, etc. I'll delete this when they answer.